# (config.filter_parameters) equivalent for Rails 2.3.5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, logging, ruby-on-rails-2

I need a config.filter_parameters (Rails 3.x.x) equivalent for Rails 2.3.x

```
module SampleApp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # Configure sensitive parameters which will be filtered from the log file.
    config.filter_parameters += [:password]
  end
end
```

That works on Rails 3 but it need that functionality in Rails 2.3.x.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put the following inside your controller:

```
filter_parameter_logging :password
```

You could put it into your application controller and have the behavior extend to all your controllers or you can put it into just the controllers that need filtering.  I recommend the application controller approach because it is more of a whitelist approach that is less prone to error.